# Identify a movie about security tester who is tricked into working for secret agency

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched a movie on tv between a month or two ago. It's a modern action movie /thriller, made after 2010. The annoying part is that I started watching ten or so minutes after the start, I can't remember the main actors and the movie has in my opinion a generic name, like "Security protocol" or something. I had to leave the house before seeing the ending so I'd like to find the movie.

The main character is working as a security, vulnerability and penetration tester for a security company. His job is to find a way to trick or break all sort of security equipment the company has patents for so he can gain access. Some of that equipment doesn't exist in real world at the moment thus the feel of "10 years into the future" sci-fi.

As an example, there is electronic lock which scans both fingerprints and needs a password. He soaks the lock in bleach and freezes it with liquid nitrogen to break it. Instead of keeping the doors locked, it unlocks them! Thus exploitable vulnerability. He also devises a way to open top of the line locked suitcase/strongbox, using gum and soft drink or something like that. Tricking face ID's on phones. And similar things like that. His job is somehow tricking or breaking hardware to gain access where he shouldn't have.

The movie starts with Main Character realizing that the company he works for doesn't own the patents and licenses for some of the security products he has been testing and breaking. Things like top of the line electronic locks that worlds militaries and intelligence agencies are using to hide their most secret secrets. He says so to his female coworker and assistant as they are preparing the presentation for the higher ups in the company and she says she'll check it out, probably some legal issues and improperly filed paperwork or something like that.

After the presentation, the Main Character goes to ten day vacation with his daughter. When he comes back, the company is gone, the testing site he has spent between 1 to 5 years working for is stripped clean of all the lab equipment, his coworkers are not replying to his phone calls and everyone is gone. One of his coworkers finally gets in contact with him and tries to kill Main Character and his daughter and makes them get into a car while threatening them with a gun. He saves himself by getting into a car crash and the bad guy hitting the head on the windshield.

Main Character flies to Europe with his daughter and goes to corporate building of the company he works for. Turns out they have never heard about him, they never used hiring agency he was hired by and they don't and never have had a department in USA. Cut to a different scene. Turns out that the female coworker was his handler in a secret agency, the assassin he killed was in her employ and that there is shady stuff happening with her higher ups trying to hide their tracks and throw her under the bus.

The chase is on, while the Main Character breaks into all sort of things in an attempt to find what is going on while trying to protect himself and his daughter.

Comment: I know this one is answered already, but are there any fantasy or science fiction aspects to the film?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because _Erased_ doesn’t contain any science fiction or fantasy elements, it’s just a normal action thriller

Comment: It is already answered. I didn't know that when I asked the question. There is some quite advanced sci fi technology in it but ok.

Comment: None of the technology described in the question is particularly advanced, though. Maybe it was in 2012, but not as of a month or two ago.

Comment: I am inclined to agree. Face recognition on consumer smartphones has been supported since at least Android 4.0 (2011). Fingerprint scanning locks are decades old, and if there is not a commercial variant that requires a password as well, it would have been easy to design. The technology involved was not speculative even at the time it was written.

Comment: On the other hand if we have some movie form 1930 with rocket roaring to space - it is still sci fi, right? So if we have some sci fi elements for the 2012 (absent in real life in 2012) then it is sci fi.

Comment: @jo1storm can you name any sci fi elements (as of 2012)?

Comment: @jo1storm: Sorry if it feels like we're complaining about your question. I honestly wasn't certain, from the description, if this fell under science fiction. It sounded like it could be (c.f. *Paycheck* which has some similar themes of reverse-engineering), but what they listed sounded like standard technology for the time. It doesn't mean that your question is bad, and could well be that your memories had the technology more advanced (although that would have been a good thing to mention).

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I misremembered it with another movie. I guess there are not that sci fi things. I agree that the question should be closed.

Comment: @jo1storm: No worries. It's happened to me a few times before. And it does sound like an interesting film.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is [**"Erased" (2012)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erased_(2012_film)) with Aaron Eckhart, which was also released as **"The Expatriate"** in some countries.  [**IMDB**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1645155/), [**Trailer**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TzKoiTDNKPw).

> Ben is supposed to test security systems made by the company for whom
> he works, but returning to the office one night, he finds that the
> entire company has disappeared, including the employees and his entire
> identity along with them. He soon finds out he's going to be
> terminated -- and by terminated, like in the ground terminated, so he
> and his daughter take off. He's determined to find out what's going
> on.

Workplace:
[image]

Hacking the phone:
[image]

Empty office:
[image]

Search string:
thriller movie test security equipment save daughter